# Second Order Cone Program with Quadratic Objective Function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, second-order-cone-programming

The standard form for a Second Order Cone Program (SOCP) is

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\min _{x} f^{T} x \\
\left\|A_{i} x+b_{i}\right\|_{2} \leq c_{i}^{T} x+d_{i}, i=1, \ldots, m
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $ A_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{k_{i} \times n}, b_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{k_{i}}, c_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \text { and } d_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$.

If the objective is quadratic instead we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\min _{x} x^{T}\Sigma x + f^Tx \\ 
\left\|A_{i} x+b_{i}\right\|_{2} \leq c_{i}^{T} x+d_{i}, i=1, \ldots, m
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Can someone help me how can I reformulation this to SCOP. I found this link https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#sec-cqo-modeling-qset where they state that

Assume $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. The convex inequality
$$
(1 / 2) x^{T} Q x+c^{T} x+r \leq 0
$$
may be rewritten as
$$
\begin{aligned}
t+c^{T} x+r &=0 \\
x^{T} Q x & \leq 2 t.
\end{aligned}
$$
Can someone help me with what exactly t is?

e.g. I have  $Q = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
 0& 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$, $c =\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$  and $r = 0$, how can I rewrite this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $t=-c^Tx-r.$ Then clearly $t+c^Tx+r=0$ and
$$\frac{1}{2}x^TQx-t=\frac{1}{2}x^TQx+c^Tx+r\leq 0$$
implies
$$
x^TQx\leq 2t.
$$
We are adding an extra variable ("$t$") together with an extra equation to constrain that variable. Rewriting your equation we get the two equations
$$
t+\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}x=0
$$
and
$$
x^T 
\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}x\leq 2t.
$$
If $x=(x_1,x_2)$ then these equations are
$$
t+2x_1+2x_2=0
$$
and
$$
2x_1^2+2x_2^2\leq 2t.
$$